# Synchronizing and panning to different point in Leaflet maps

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, r-leaflet

I am trying to create a shiny application that presents three-star maps simulating urban and rural night skies with a drop-down sector that will allow you to choose constellations (right now it is just placeholder values c1 c2 c3) Also the maps should be synchronized when panning or zooming
(also I know lat and long don't work with stars normally but this is projected on a world map)

Right now this code running all three maps stays synchronized when zooming or dragging the map manually. Once I select an option from the drop-down menu c1, c2, or c3 the third map updates correctly but the first two don't do anything AND are no longer synchronized at all

Here is the star data if you wold like to run it yourself it is only 2 Mb https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o6wmCc8G76Wj0A6VjOWe0YP53AMOcOyQ/view?usp=sharing

```r
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet.minicharts)

stars <- readOGR(dsn = "./astro/stars.shp", layer = "stars")
asterism <- readOGR(dsn = "./astro/asterism.shp", layer = "asterism")
milkyway <- readOGR(dsn = "./astro/milkyway.shp", layer = "milkyway")
constell <- readOGR(dsn = "./astro/constell.shp", layer = "constell")

getFillColor <- function(val) {
  if (val == 8 || val == 9) return("#6d6d80")
  else if (val == 7) return("#4d4d5a")
  else if (val == 6) return("#3e3e46")
  else if (val == 5) return("#323236")
  else if (val == 4) return("#2c292f")
  else if (val == 3) return("#272323")
  else if (val == 2) return("#18171e")
  else if (val == 1) return("#0b0b0e")
  else return("#000000")
}

tb = 9
ts = 1

# Create reactive values
rv <- reactiveValues(
  YOUR_LONGITUDE = 100,
  YOUR_LATITUDE = 40,
  YOUR_ZOOM_LEVEL = 4
)

getnelm <- function(input_val) {
  output <- 8 - (input_val - 1) * 0.5
  return(output)
}

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4, leafletOutput("original_map")),
    column(4, leafletOutput("subsetted_map")),
    column(4, leafletOutput("third_map"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12, 
           selectInput("c_selector", label = "Choose c:", 
                       choices = c("c1", "c2", "c3"), selected = "c1")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$c_selector, {
    if (input$c_selector == "c1") {
      rv$YOUR_LONGITUDE <- 100
      rv$YOUR_LATITUDE <- 40
      rv$YOUR_ZOOM_LEVEL <- 4
    } else if (input$c_selector == "c2") {
      rv$YOUR_LONGITUDE <- 101
      rv$YOUR_LATITUDE <- 41
      rv$YOUR_ZOOM_LEVEL <- 5
    } else if (input$c_selector == "c3") {
      rv$YOUR_LONGITUDE <- 103
      rv$YOUR_LATITUDE <- 42
      rv$YOUR_ZOOM_LEVEL <- 6
    }
  })

  generateMap <- function(starsData, val, subsetCondition, longitude, latitude, zoom) {
    limiter <- getnelm(val)
    subsetted_stars <- subset(stars, Stars_Na_1 <= limiter)
    smax = limiter
    smin = min(subsetted_stars$Stars_Na_1, na.rm = TRUE)
    subsetted_stars$trans <- (ts * smin + (tb - ts) * subsetted_stars$Stars_Na_1 - smax * tb) / (smin - smax)

    leaflet() %>%
      addPolygons(
        data = constell,
        fillColor = getFillColor(val),  # Use the getFillColor function
        fillOpacity = 1,
        color = "white",
        weight = 1
      ) %>%
      addPolygons(
        data = milkyway,
        fillColor = ifelse(milkyway$type == "inner", "#BEE8FF", "#6699CD"),
        fillOpacity = 0.2,
        color = "white",
        weight = 0
      ) %>%
      addPolylines(
        data = asterism,
        color = "#6699CD",
        weight = 2
      ) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(
        data = subsetted_stars,
        lat = ~coordinates(subsetted_stars)[, 2],
        lng = ~coordinates(subsetted_stars)[, 1],
        color = "white",
        fillColor = "white",
        fillOpacity = ~trans / 9,
        weight = 0,
        radius = ~trans,
        popup = subset(starsData, subsetCondition)$Name
      ) %>%
      setView(lng = longitude, lat = latitude, zoom = zoom) %>%
      syncWith("mapSyncGroup")  # Add synchronization to the map
  }

  output$original_map <- renderLeaflet({
    generateMap(stars, 6, TRUE, rv$YOUR_LONGITUDE, rv$YOUR_LATITUDE, rv$YOUR_ZOOM_LEVEL)
  })

  output$subsetted_map <- renderLeaflet({
    generateMap(stars, 4, TRUE, rv$YOUR_LONGITUDE, rv$YOUR_LATITUDE, rv$YOUR_ZOOM_LEVEL)
  })

  output$third_map <- renderLeaflet({
    generateMap(stars, 2, TRUE, rv$YOUR_LONGITUDE, rv$YOUR_LATITUDE, rv$YOUR_ZOOM_LEVEL)
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```